# Plural/Singular Subject/Object Agreement

Tags: singular-vs-plural, quotations

Donald Trump's (in)famous quote "Grab 'em by the pussy".

As an English learner, I'm confused, why not "puss*ies*".

"Them" is plural, so their puss*ies* should be plural too.

Comment: Couldn't you come up with a less unpleasant example?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is correct to be singular; for example:

> **Grab them by their jersey.**

since each player only has one (usually).

The same is:

> **Pat them on the back.**

not:

> **Pat them on the backs.**

Whereas:

> **Kick them in the knees.**

is plural since each player has *two* knees (shins).